# Android Consume Rest API over LAN through Access Point

Tags: android, sockets, retrofit, rest, access-point

I can not seem to find out how to consume Rest API, which is written in PHP, **over LAN through Access Point on my Android device**. I came across **Socket.io** but that requires the server to be written using Socket.io as well. I could not find **Retrofit** example for this. I also could not find any example using **sockets**.

The reason for doing this is that there are always internet issues so we have deployed a local server and have to connect this LAN server through Access Point.

Any direction in this regard is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that **my tablet was not configured properly**. As soon as I configured my tablet properly to use local network, everything worked absolutely fine.